# IPv6 link-local only core network

Tags: ipv6, ip-link-local

When planning an IPv6 strategy is it possible to have link-local only addresses within the core transit network (sort of analogous to a BGP-free MPLS core)?

If not why not?

If yes are there any disadvantages to using this model; maybe the potential of making troubleshooting a little more difficult, such a traceroutes not working?

Are there similar deployment models that should be considered (such as a ULA core)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is certainly possible and has been done. Usually each device gets a global loopback address for example for iBGP sessions and remote management.

Take a look at [RFC 7404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7404), it describes exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

In theory is possible to use link-local IPv6 as gateway address, but IPv6 link-local accessible only from local subnet (it nonroutable), so then how to access equipment for management over IPv6 form other subnets?